# Why does Boost.Multiprecision not use the largest possible word size?

Tags: c++, boost, biginteger, bigint, multiprecision

I have noticed that cpp_int backend of Boost.Multiprecion library uses 32-bit unsigned integer as a word (limb) on 64-bit architecture. The requirement for 64-bit word to be used is availability of native 128-bit integer in compiler (that might be a clue). Why is that?

More about the "clue". `limb_type` is defined as `detail::largest_unsigned_type<32>::type` for compilers without native 128-bit integer support in file `boost/multiprecision/cpp_int/cpp_int_config.hpp`. There is also a type called `double_limb_type`.

Comment: Where did you get that "clue"? That's a good starting point for people who might now some more background reading that

Comment: It's possibly because, to do operations on the unit words and get overflow, you need to have a larger type available. I.e. multiplying two 32 words gives you a 64 bit result.